# I am getting wrong date after converting by moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

My code is

```
console.log(moment(new Date('2016-05-24T18:50:05.000')).format('LL'));
```

It should be *24 may 2016* but it gives me *25 may 2016*.

Can any one help me.

Comment: Could this be a timezone issue?  Consider specifying UTC timezone.

Comment: No only for this date it is happening otherwise i checked for others it is working fine. you can check in example in plukr [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/e8cIXxajUmE7ggVXueTG?p=preview)

Comment: Moment assumes the time is local if you do not specify a timezone  So, if you are on Pacific Time or Mountain Time or Central Time, that would mean May 25 in UTC (remember, UTC would be at least 6 hours ahead of  you).  Try the string `'2016-05-24T18:50:05.000Z'` to specify UTC timezone.

Comment: By the way, the plunker code works for me as expected (I get May 24, 2016 as alert) since I am UTC+5.

Comment: Alternatively, you can specify a locale for moment.

Comment: ok i will add locale.

Comment: Add a utcOffset too. :)

Comment: problem is solved now thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to specify the date as UTC.**

You can do so in either of the following ways:

```
console.log(moment(new Date('2016-05-24T18:50:05.000Z')).format('LL'));
```

Where, the Z specifies that the time is UTC. Or:

```
console.log(moment.utc(new Date('2016-05-24T18:50:05.000')).format('LL'));
```

**You can pass an ISO 8601 date string to moment directly.**

There is no need to wrap the string in a javascript Date object. Then your code becomes:

```
console.log(moment('2016-05-24T18:50:05.000Z').format('LL'));
```

Or:

```
console.log(moment.utc('2016-05-24T18:50:05.000').format('LL'));
```

Comment: console.log(moment.utc(new Date()).format('LL')); It shows yesterday date not today why?

Comment: new Date() creates a date in local time, moment.utc() forces moment to interpret the date as UTC. format('LL') displays the date in local time. Only use moment.utc() instead of moment() if you want the datetime that you are passing as an argument to be interpretted as utc.

Comment: Why are you calling `new Date` at all?